# Disable "Constant conditions & exceptions" inspection for field in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm using a framework (Minecraft Forge) that injects specific objects into `public static final` fields with `null` values (through the `@CapabilityInject` and `@ObjectHolder` annotations). Unfortunately whenever I reference one of these fields in a context that doesn't allow `null` values, the "Constant conditions & exceptions" inspection in IntelliJ IDEA warns me that the field may be `null` (because it doesn't know about the injection).

I know that these fields won't be `null` when they're accessed, so I'd like to disable the warning for them.

Is there a way to disable the warning for a specific field or all fields in a class? Adding `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")` or `//noinspection ConstantConditions` to the field doesn't remove the warning on the field access and adding the annotation to the field's class only removes the warning in that class.

I'd like to avoid adding `//noinspection ConstantConditions` or `null`-checks to every location I access the fields from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

diesieben07 answered this in my thread on the [Minecraft Forge Forums](http://www.minecraftforge.net/forum/topic/60980-solved-disable-%E2%80%9Cconstant-conditions-exceptions%E2%80%9D-inspection-for-field-in-intellij-idea/?do=findComment&comment=285019).

The solution/workaround is to create a method that always returns `null`, annotate it with `@Nonnull` and `@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")` and then use that to initialise the field that will be injected into.

For example:

```java
public class Injection {

    @CapabilityInject
    public static final Capability<IItemHandler> CAPABILITY = getNull();

    @Nonnull
    @SuppressWarnings({"ConstantConditions", "SameReturnValue"})
    private static <T> T getNull() {
        return null;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        // No warning
        Capability<IItemHandler> capability = CAPABILITY;
    }
}
```

---

Salamander offered an alternative solution in my thread on [WTDWTF](https://what.thedailywtf.com/post/1242786).

They suggested moving the initialisation to a static initialiser block instead of initialising the fields inline. This seems less hackish than a method that always returns `null`, but it also adds a lot of clutter if there are a lot of fields to initialise (which there are in my case).

For example:

```java
public class Injection {

    @CapabilityInject
    public static final Capability<IItemHandler> CAPABILITY;

    static {
        CAPABILITY = null;
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        // No warning
        Capability<IItemHandler> capability = CAPABILITY;
    }
}
```